# What do i get from setting this TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

I happen to find examples that uses this construct though I am not sure what can I get from this?

Does it means that all select statements in a stateless EJB should follow this?

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EmployeeService")
    EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<Department> findAllEmployees() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e",
        Employee.class)
        .getResultList();
    }
```

What do I get from this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you get is:

1. Relatively formal way to tell that your method does not need transaction (as consequence you know for example that it will not call persist, merge or remove in EntityManager).
2. *Possible* performance optimization in some cases.

   - No need to create/pass transaction. According [Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html#bncip): "Because transactions involve overhead, this attribute may improve performance."
   - According other sources (for example Pro JPA 2) it offers implementations possibility to not create *managed* entities at all (which is likely heavier operation than creating detached entities right away).

Comment: How does the the EntityManager execute the query without a transaction? /confused/